# Escape the content of a variable

Tags: batch-file, escaping

In my batch script I need to pass the current directory path to a program, escaped.

So, when my batch script is running in `C:\Program Files\` it has to pass `C:\\Program Files\\` to the called program.

How can I do that? Many thanks.

Background: The called program expects a replacement string for a regex operation, thus it will expect a group parameter when using `\` only. The data that will be targeted by the regex operation is used by a software that won't accept relative paths or environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is `%~dp0` the current path where the batch are located
But there is also `%CD%`, the current working directory.

try something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "x=%CD%"
set "x=%x:\=\\%"
echo %x%
```

as mentioned by @joey you can directly call the current directory like this `%CD:\=\\%`

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just inline those and use `%CD:\=\\%`?

Comment: @Joey To apologize, I left the idea to do that with `%~dp0` but then I thought better of what he was thinking, it was `cd`

Comment: No need to apologise; just wondering. And there are lots of weird cargo-cult ideas floating around in batch files, so just to make sure :)